# Magento Fishpig how to get post image by id

Tags: magento, fishpig

I have use Fishpig extension in my website.

But i need to show Next and Previous link with it's appropriate featured image.

Can anyone please provide appropriate suggestion for this requirement.

**Thanks,**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Yes, i know that but i just need to help for any hint to customization.
If you know anything then let me know. otherwise  its Ok.

Comment: I gave you a hint - and that's to post on a forum where this might be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

The following code loads a post with the ID of 5 and if a featured image is set, it displays the image and a link to the post.

```
<?php $post = Mage::getModel('wordpress/post')->load(5) ?>
<?php if ($post->getId()): ?>
    <?php if ($image = $post->getFeaturedImage()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $image->getAvailableImage() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?>"/>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can find more information on how to get different sized images from the featured image object at the URL below:

https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/post-images/

Answer (score 0):

The following article explains how to get an image object from a post object.

https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/post-images/

Specifically:

```
<?php // $post is already defined ?>
<?php if ($featuredImage = $post->getFeaturedImage()): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $featuredImage->getAvailableImage() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?>"/>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, But it's display current post image only. 
As per my requirement. I need specific post id image.  

For Example : If i specified post id 5 then show post id fifth featured image.

Comment: Have you used Magento before? $post = Mage::getModel('wordpress/post')->load(5);

Comment: Thanks,
I have check this  $post = Mage::getModel('wordpress/post')->load(5);

But i did not get post featured image url in array response.

Please check if i am wrong then let me know.